# Adding Babel plugin to Vue CLI project not working

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli

I'm trying to add Babel to an already existing Vue CLI project. Following the directions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-babel

I tried:

```
vue add babel
```

this results in the error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-plugin-babel - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'vue-cli-plugin-babel@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tomlewis1/.npm/_logs/2019-10-21T17_11_26_039Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error -D vue-cli-plugin-babel
```

I've tried deleting NPM cache and updating NPM, node, and Vue CLI. Should I be specifying another registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error. Thinking it might be a bug, but using `vue add @vue/cli-plugin-babel` seems to work. Give that a try!